# I can't find the error in this line of code

Tags: javascript

This function is created inside an object, and I can't figure out why I get this error

```
addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
   const dish = {
     name,
     price
   };
   this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
 };



error :
addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Did you mean `function addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {`?

Comment: Show us the surrounding context.

Comment: what about last `name` and `price`?

Comment: in which environment do you use it?

Comment: I use it on CodeCademy

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your object `dish` and its two properties `name` and `price`, but you haven't assigned any values to these properties. The "missing identifier" the exception is complaining about is the operator `:` which is used to assign values to properties in object literals. It should probably go like this:

EDIT: also have to declare it as a function using `function` keyword.

```
function addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
   const dish = {
     name : dishName,
     price : dishPrice
   };
   this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
 };
```

Comment: Unexpected identifier, again

Comment: Just noticed you aren't declaring your function as a function. add the `function` keyword to the beginning of your function signature `function addDishToCourse(...) {`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: Something in the statement before this one isn't right then. Forgot a parenthesis maybe?

Comment: yep, I forgot to put the comma before the function

Answer (score 0):

try with  arrow function like this:

```
const addDishToCourse = (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) => {
   const dish = {
     name,
     price
   };
   this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
 };
```

or with regular function

```
function addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
   const dish = {
     name,
     price
   };
   this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
 };
```